# What exactly is the maximum number of celestial coins you can hoard in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I am playing the Xbox One version and the ingame description states that seven is the maximum number. However on the official wiki [here](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Coin). It states that 14 is the maximum. Also on the [Vault of Piety](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Vault_of_Piety) page, it shows that some items cost 11 celestial coins. How is this possible? Which piece of information is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Module 6, you could have at most 7 coins.  Starting with Module 6, you can have up to 14 coins.

You can earn up to 2 coins per day if you invoke the maximum number of times.

Before Module 6 failing to invoke for 24 hours plus a grace period (of about 4 hours I think) caused the celestial coins to go away.  Now, they stick around.

Comment: That makes sense... since Elemental Evil hasn't been released on the One yet. Thanks.. that cleared it up for me.